# Using gevent with python xmlrpclib

Tags: python, gevent, xmlrpclib

Is it possible to use python's standard libs xmlrpclib with gevent? Currently i'm tried to use monkey.patch_all(), but without success.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

import gevent

import time

import xmlrpclib
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

import urllib2

def fetch(url):
        g = gevent.spawn(urllib2.urlopen, url)
        return g.get().read()
def is_even(n):
    return n%2 == 0

def req(url):
        return fetch(url)

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))
print "Listening on port 8000..."
server.register_function(is_even, "is_even")
server.register_function(req, "req")
server.serve_forever()
```

urllib2.urlopen is blocking server. It looks to me, that monkey.patch_all did not patched socket, that's why it blocks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The socket is patched fine, but there are other problems with your code.

First, this

```
def fetch(url):
    g = gevent.spawn(urllib2.urlopen, url)
    return g.get().read()
```

is the same as

```
def fetch(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

You're spawning a new greenlet here but then blocking the current one until that new one is done. It does not make things concurrent. It's exactly the same as just running urlopen and waiting for it to finish.

Second, in order to take advantage of [gevent](http://www.gevent.org) there got to be more than one lightweight thread (greenlet) running at the same time.

SimpleXMLRPCServer, however, is defined as

```
class SimpleXMLRPCServer(SocketServer.TCPServer,
                         SimpleXMLRPCDispatcher):
```

which means it serves one connection at a time.

If you make your own `SimpleXMLRPCServer` class, but use `ThreadingTCPServer` instead of `TCPServer`, you should be able to benefit from using gevent here.

[`monkey.patch_all()`](http://gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html) patches `threading` to become greenlet-based, so such server will spawn a new greenlet for each new connection.

Comment: Thank You! Threaded version is working as expected! But how to return result asyncrhonously from urllib2.urlopen?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "return result asynchronously". What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Correct me if i im wrong. Each new connection is spawned in new greenlet, so i dont need to spawn urlopen in new greenlet. when urlopen is called and if theres more than one connection or new event occured gevent switches to other coroutine, when content arrives on socket it switches back to urlopen coroutine and returns result.

Comment: that's right, if server spawns a new greenlet for each connection, urlopen will only block the current greenlet and will let the others run.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarification, and thanks for open sourcing such great lib.