# How to make more than one xmlrpc calls to different xmlrpc servers at a time

Tags: python, xml-rpc, python-multithreading, xmlrpclib, simplexmlrpcserver

Is there any way to make multiple calls from an xmlrpc client to different xmlrpc servers at a time.

My Server code looks like this: (I'll have this code runnning in two machines, server1 & server2)

```
class TestMethods(object):
    def printHello(self):
        while(1):
            time.sleep(10)
            print "HELLO FROM SERVER"
            return True

class ServerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("x.x.x.x", 8000))
        self.server.register_instance(TestMethods())
    def run(self):
        self.server.serve_forever()

server = ServerThread()
server.start()
```

My Client code looks like this:

```
import xmlrpclib

client1 = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://x.x.x.x:8080") # registering with server 1
client2 = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http:/x.x.x.x:8080") # registering with server 2
ret1 = client1.printHello()
ret2 = client2.printHello()
```

Now, on the 10th second I'll get a response from server1 and on the 20th second I'll get a response from server2 which is unfortunately not what I want.
I'm trying to make calls to two machines at a time so that I get the response back from those two machines at a time.

PLease help me out, THanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

There a a few different ways to do this.

## [python multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Is the built-in python module for running stuff in parallel.  The docs are fairly clear.  The easiest & most extensible way using this method is with a 'Pool' of workers that you can add as many to as you want.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import xmlrpclib

def hello_client(url):
    client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url)
    return client.printHello()

p = Pool(processes=10)  # maximum number of requests at once.

servers_list = ['http://x.x.x.x:8080', 'http://x.x.x.x:8080']
# you can add as many other servers into that list as you want!

results = p.map(hello_client, servers_list)

print results
```

## [twisted python](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

twisted python is an amazing clever system for writing all kinds of multithreaded / parallel / multiprocess stuff.  The documentation is a bit confusing.

## [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

Another non-blocking python framework.  Also very cool.  [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191858/python-tornado-non-blocking-xmlrpc-client) about XMLRPC, python, and tornado.

## [gevent](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Gevent.html)

A 'magic' way of allowing blocking tasks in python to happen in the background.  Very very cool.  And [here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065079/using-gevent-with-python-xmlrpclib) about how to use XMLRPC in python with gevent.

Comment: That does not works on my side ... it just pull information from on Xen server of the list :-/